# Xcode 7.3 - warnings aren't showing up & can't search project

Tags: ios, xcode

Since I've upgraded to Xcode 7.3 I've noticed that I always get 'no results' when searching my workspace and as well no warnings show up in the warnings pane. Occasionally it works for a few minutes and dies again. Restarting my computer,  Xcode, and reinstalling hasn't helped.

Is anyone else experiencing this or found a resolution/workaround?

I co-installed 7.2.1 to compare and both search and warning are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode, backup your project and try this on the copy:

1. locate your `.xcodeproj` file on finder.
2. right click it and choose `show package contents`.
3. delete everything there except for `project.pbxproj`.
4. open the project again on xcode.

if you are using cocoapods then do this first.

1. open a terminal window where the `.xcworkspace` file is.
2. type `pod deintegrate`, to uninstall all pods
3. delete the `.xcworkspace` file.
4. do the first 3 items of the previous list on your `.xcodeproj` file.
5. type `pod install` to install your pods again and generate a brand new `.xcworkspace`.

open your project again on xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with warnings in swift frameworks. If you have any swift framework in your application, check if you have this frameworks in build tab of your scheme.

- Go to `Edit Scheme...`
- Click on `Build`
- Add framework target to targets (if missing)