# Why are IBAction methods missing from the storyboard exit button?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am attempting to perform an unwind segue. I have tested my logic in a brand new project and was able to validate the pattern. However in my actual working project the same pattern does not work.

I am attempting to unwind from my `SettingsController` to my `EditorViewController`. However the `@IBAction` inside of my `EditorViewController` is not showing up in the exit storyboard button of the `SettingsController`.

## EditorViewController.swift

```
class EditorViewController: UIViewController {
    // Snippet
    @IBAction func unwindToEditor(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        // Some logic
    }
}
```

## Drag and drop a segue from one controller to another

[image: Creating a Push Segue between controllers]

## Attempt to associate EditorViewController#unwindToEditor with SettingsController

[image: As you can see the unwindToEditor method is missing]

The `unwindToEditor` method is unavailable.

Things I have tried but did not help:

- Restarting Xcode
- Remove custom class from view controller and adding it again
- Removing Xcode's Derived Data
- Created custom Obj-C header file
- Used multiple method signatures on my unwind action

Note:

I have discovered that this list of usable IBActions in the "Presenting Segues" under the 'Exit' button of a controller are only pulling from one of my controllers. Perhaps there is an issue with populating this list across multiple controllers?

## Discovered work around

It seems that even if my method is missing from the list, if I go and choose one of the methods that do exist and manually change the method calls in the attributes inspector of the unwind segue it will call the appropriate (which was missing) method.

Comment: which version of swift are you using?

Comment: Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1

Comment: swift 3 emphasizes on named parameter either give one or neglect as `@IBAction func unwindToEditor(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue)`

Comment: I have tried that unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue with populating the list of "Presenting Segues" as my only two existing actions that show up use the following signatures... `unwindToSomeView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an unwind segue method.

Simply do this:

1. on your `EditorViewController` add this code:

   ```
   @IBAction func unwindToEditorViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
   ```
2. on your `SettingsController` control drag from your button to the exit icon of `SettingsController` and choose `unwindoToEditorViewController` from the list.

   [image]

Voilà!

Comment: Thats the problem, in step 2 unwindToEditorViewController is missing

Comment: have you verified if there is any typo on the code like I have typed on #1? You put that code on the controller you want to return, right?

Comment: While you are at it, try [this other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38659848/316469) of mine.